# Do "Old Passwords" have an expiration?

Tags: security, password-management

There are some systems that keep track of "old passwords" for increased security, like Databases, Domain Controllers, personal pages (Like Facebook) etc.

Do these "old passwords" have an expiration? Eg. After (x) months/after (x) many new passwords, I can use an old password to replace my new one?

Comment: It depends from the policy, i doubt facebook pass wil expire, DC propably has option for pass expire, and never heard of db pass expiration.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the administrator puts something like

```
PASS_MAX_DAYS   99999
PASS_MIN_DAYS   0
PASS_WARN_AGE   7
```

In etc/login.defs